# How to show implementation of a method using Javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

Even if it does not sound as a BP I was wondering if there is any way to show on the JavaDoc the implementation of a method.

I am wondering if is there any '@code'-like that automatically shows the implementation of the instead of describing it.

Comment: What is a "BP"?

Comment: Is it really necessary to show the code in the JavaDoc? - I think normally only the API should be there.

Comment: I know it is not necessary I was just wondering if is there a way to do it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no way to generate the code automatically, best you can do is the following.

You can add a `@apiNote` annotation to your docs and add:

```
/**
 * @apiNote
 * Description of example implementation...
 *
 * <pre>{@code
 *     // Code implementation example.
 * }</pre>
 */
```

### Example from Java 8 JDK

Via GrepCode:

> [**JDK / jdk / openjdk / 8u40-b25 / java.util.Comparator**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Comparator.java#Comparator.thenComparing%28java.util.Comparator%29)

[image: GrepCode java.util.Comparator.thenComparing]

#### JDK 8 Update 112 Source Code

```java
/**
 * Returns a lexicographic-order comparator with another comparator.
 * If this {@code Comparator} considers two elements equal, i.e.
 * {@code compare(a, b) == 0}, {@code other} is used to determine the order.
 *
 * <p>The returned comparator is serializable if the specified comparator
 * is also serializable.
 *
 * @apiNote
 * For example, to sort a collection of {@code String} based on the length
 * and then case-insensitive natural ordering, the comparator can be
 * composed using following code,
 *
 * <pre>{@code
 *     Comparator<String> cmp = Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)
 *             .thenComparing(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
 * }</pre>
 *
 * @param  other the other comparator to be used when this comparator
 *         compares two objects that are equal.
 * @return a lexicographic-order comparator composed of this and then the
 *         other comparator
 * @throws NullPointerException if the argument is null.
 * @since 1.8
 */
default Comparator<T> thenComparing(Comparator<? super T> other) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(other);
    return (Comparator<T> & Serializable) (c1, c2) -> {
        int res = compare(c1, c2);
        return (res != 0) ? res : other.compare(c1, c2);
    };
}
```